# Scaping all the names from a website

Tags: python, html

I am currently trying to scape all of the names from a specific website. I was making some progress by following a guide on python-guide.org. I was able to scrape a lot of the information off of a certain site, but not the information I was after. Here is my code so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page =     requests.get('http://www.behindthename.com/names/gender/feminine/usage/african')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


#This will create a list of buyers:
Names = tree.xpath('//div[@class="browsename"]/text()')

print 'Names: ', Names
```

Unfortunately, that returns a lot of information, but not the list of names. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I am certain it has to do with the @class="bowsername". I'm not very familiar with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe, you should use:

```
//div[@class="browsename"]/b/a/text()
```

In chrome, you can use F12 to inspect elements, then use CTRL + F, and input your xpath. Chrome will show you what elements you choose.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!